# Ruby Shoes video element issue?

Tags: ruby, windows, vlc, shoes

If I try to use the video element on shoes 3.8, player borders will be completely transparent.

Before to play the video, the player looks fine:

[image]

But when I play the video, player sides will become transparent:

[image]

If I stop the video instead, the whole player will become transparent.
I can pass VLC options as well, so may is there a transparency option for VideoLan?
I tried to check VLC Docs but there are tons of options and i'm not good in video embeddings.

This is my code:

```
require "shoes/videoffi"

Shoes.app :width => 1024, :height => 768 do

 stack :fill => true, :margin => 4, :width =>640, :height => 320 do
   @vid = video "D:\\Download\\1.mp4", vlc_options: ["--xlib", "--video-on-top"], autoplay: false
 end

 if @vid.loaded == true
   #@vid.play
 end

 flow {
   button ("play") {@vid.play}
   button ("pause") {@vid.pause}
   button ("stop") {@vid.stop}
 }
end
```

Comment: This could be a bug, so if you've got a snippet of code that can reproduce this problem it's worth raising with the Shoes team.

Comment: @tadman I used their example script, i just replaced defalut video with mine. Best suggestion is to open an issue on GitHub? Thanks

Comment: It's worth adding the sample code you used that can reproduce the problem, and if nobody can figure it out here, then take it up with the Shoes team on GitHub. This may be a known issue, you'd have to look at the history there.

Comment: @tadman I've updated my question. I've searched in all their issues and no one is regarding this too.

Comment: I think you've found an interesting bug that's worth reporting, then. Nice!

Comment: Your code runs fine in my Shoes (build 3.3.7)